# Dask "Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray"

Tags: python, bigdata, dask, multiple-conditions, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to use Dask instead of pandas since the data size I'm analyzing is quite large. I wanted to add a flag column based on several conditions.

```
import dask.array as da
data['Flag'] = da.where((data['col1']>0) & (data['col2']>data['col4'] | data['col3']>data['col4']), 1, 0).compute()
```

But, then I got the following error message. The above code works perfectly when using `np.where` with pandas dataframe, but didn't work with `dask.array.where`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If numpy works and the operation is row-wise, then one solution is to use `.map_partitions`:

```py
def create_flag(data):
    data['Flag'] = np.where((data['col1']>0) & (data['col2']>data['col4'] | data['col3']>data['col4']), 1, 0)
    return data

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(create_flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dask.dataframe.Series.where`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.where.html#dask-dataframe-series-where) to achieve the same result but without computing. Or better yet, you could make use of the fact that True/False values can be converted directly into 1/0 by simply promoting the type to `int` (see below).

Both of these options have the advantage of keeping all operations native to dask.dataframe and thereby giving the scheduler more visibility into the operation (and thus more freedom to optimize, manage memory, etc.) than non-dask operations called with map_partitions or directly assigning a computed result.

```py
data['Flag'] = (
    (data['col1']>0)
    & ((data['col2']>data['col4']) | (data['col3']>data['col4']))
).astype(int)
```

Comment: Agree with what you write re: visibility, but one advantage of `map_partitions` is that it can combine multiple operations, potentially reducing the task burden on the scheduler.

Comment: great point! maybe I misunderstand this part of dask.dataframe's performance - if the scheudler isn't at risk of being overwhelmed, would map_partitions perform better for a simple op like this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method, but I still only get True and False, instead of 1 and 0.

Comment: did you include the `.astype(int)`?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: if the overall number of tasks is small, then not sure there's much of a performance boost (maybe some edge cases).

Comment: @Michael Delsgado. Yes, I included .astype(int) at the end just as what you wrote here.